# Number of labeled non-isomorphic trees on $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Is there any algorithm to build or count the labeled non-isomorphic trees on $n$ vertices ?

Comment: Is this the same as trees on unlabeled vertices?  If so, it is http://oeis.org/A000055

Comment: Not at all, two unlabeled trees may be isomorphic but the labeled version of the same trees may or may not be isomorphic .

Comment: How are you defining isomorphic for the labeled version?  I would think 1-3-2 and 1-2-3 are non-isomorphic as labeled trees because of the labeling, but isomorphic as unlabeled trees. If so, http://oeis.org/A000272 has the unrooted ones as $n^{n-2}$ and http://oeis.org/A000169 has the rooted ones as $n^{n-1}$

Comment: In two isomorphic labeled trees, the degree of nodes with the same number is the same, so if $Deg(Node_1) = 3$ in $T_1$ then in $T_2$ , $Deg(Node_1) = 3$ as well but the only difference is its adjacent nodes. for example $Node_1$ in $T_1$ may be adjacent to $Node_3,Node_5,Node_6$ but in $T_2$ it may be adjacent to $Node_3,Node_2,Node_7$

Comment: When people refer to an "unlabeled tree" they really mean an isomorphism class of trees.  So what do you mean by non-isomorphic labeled trees?  Do you want a specific element of each isomorphism class as a labeled tree? If you choose a specific representative for each class, the number of representatives you have is the same as the number of unlabeled trees.

Comment: I think the program [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) includes an algorithm to generate non-isomorphic trees.

Answer (score 6):

From your comment, it sounds like you consider two labeled trees isomorphic if they have the same (labeled) [degree sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence).  Thus to count the number of non-isomorphic labeled trees we'd want the number of labeled degree sequences of trees on $n$ vertices, which is ${2n-3 \choose n-1}$.

Why is it ${2n-3 \choose n-1}$?  Well, a degree sequence [corresponds to a tree](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=A_characterization_of_the_degree_sequence_of_a_tree) if and only if every degree is at least 1 and the degree sum is 2n-2.  Thus, we need the number of n-tuples of positive integers that sum to 2n-2, [which is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) ${2n-3 \choose n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $C_{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}{2(n-1) \choose n-1}$, where
$C_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ Catalan number

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! please the expression the way you wrote it is not very clear, I understand is a variation of the Catalan Number expression (or the same one) as here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number , please try to format the expression using Mathjax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference